# Attempting to pull up a list of customer purchases at a certain quantity, database seems to be ignoring my minus entirely

Tags: sql, database

I have been trying to write a set of instructions as mentioned in the title. I've tried two different variants (forewarning, I am very new to this)

```
Select d.ORDERID, c.CUSTID, c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUST_LNAME, i.INVOICEID, t.QUANTITY
from orders d, customer c, invoice i, transactions t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
((Select t.QUANTITY
from transactions t
where t.QUANTITY = '100'
and i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID
and t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID)
MINUS
(Select t.QUANTITY 
from transactions t, orders d
where t.orderid = d.orderid))
```

and

```
Select d.ORDERID, c.CUSTID, c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUST_LNAME, i.INVOICEID, t.QUANTITY
from orders d, customer c, invoice i, transactions t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
((Select t.QUANTITY
from transactions t
where t.QUANTITY = '100')
MINUS
(Select t.QUANTITY 
from transactions t 
where QUANTITY != '100'))
and i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID
and t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID
```

Both are simply supposed to pull up a short list of orders for quantities of 100. Instead the first returns every single Order ID, Customer ID, Employee name, etc etc. once for every quantity in the system. The second one finds no data at all, which I know is incorrect. If someone could point me in the right direction or tell me where I screwed up, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I see lots of tables referenced in the `FROM` clause and no `JOIN`.  Have you missed something in writing your queries?  Learn to use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: What would I use join for here?

Comment: . . Every pair of tables you have in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In The First Query, The following Subquery:

```
(Select t.QUANTITY
from transactions t
where t.QUANTITY = '100'
and i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID
and t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID)
MINUS
(Select t.QUANTITY 
from transactions t, orders d
where t.orderid = d.orderid)
```

returns 0 records. This is because you are trying to minus D1(Transactions Where Quantity= 100) - D2(Transactions) while D1 is a subset of D2.
So, The Outer Query will return All purchases of all quantities because you are using the operator NOT EXISTS.

In Second Query, The Subquery :

```
(Select t.QUANTITY
from transactions t
where t.QUANTITY = '100')
MINUS
(Select t.QUANTITY 
from transactions t 
where QUANTITY != '100')
```

returns Purchases of Quantity 100 since You are subtracting D1(Transactions where Quantity = 100 ) - D2(Transactions Where Quantity <> 100) 
which will return all D1. So, Outer Query should return all purchases with Quantity <> 100 ( due to NOT EXISTS) but Since you are not linking outerquery with subquery by

```
i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID
and t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID
```

it returns 0 records.

I suggest you read more about [MINUS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-minus-operator/) AND [NOT EXISTS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-not-exists-operator/) Operators.

For Your Problem Solution, I think if I understand well what you need, You can simply write the Query like this:

```
Select d.ORDERID, c.CUSTID, c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUST_LNAME, i.INVOICEID, t.QUANTITY
from orders d, customer c, invoice i, transactions t
Where i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID AND t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID AND t.Qunatity = 100
```

I hope this be useful for you.

Comment: I need to use division (the Where Not Exists and Minus) to get the results. Your answer is helpful but the solution you suggest would prevent me from limiting the results by order/transaction ID if I needed to.

Comment: Can you please explain more about how you need to limit the results by Order/Transaction Id ? 
Would be there a problem if you add the order/transaction Id to the Where Statement ? (Where i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID AND t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID AND t.Qunatity = 100 AND d.OrderId = 3 ) ?

Comment: If I was looking for a specific one sure, but if I was looking for a range of data then division would help a great deal. Any chance you could give an example of my statement but fixed to display properly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it helps. But I wrote you a query in the next comment, This should give you the purchases with quantity = 100 in the format you want, 
Please Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Select d.ORDERID, c.CUSTID, c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUST_LNAME, i.INVOICEID, t.QUANTITY
from orders d, customer c, invoice i, transactions t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
(Select t.QUANTITY 
from transactions t, orders d
where t.orderid = d.orderid)
MINUS
(Select t.QUANTITY
from transactions t
where t.QUANTITY <> '100'
and i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID
and t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID))

Comment: I appreciate your help, I tried what you just sent and got 'no data found' again unfortunately. I wonder if it's a problem with the database

Comment: one more thing, are you using sql Server ? if so, then please replace MINUS by EXCEPT, maybe then it will work. You should also take in consideration that EXCEPT affects performance on large datasets.  You can also use only NOT EXISTS  like in the following Query. This would perform much faster.

Comment: Select d.ORDERID, c.CUSTID, c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUST_LNAME, 
i.INVOICEID, t.QUANTITY from
 orders d, customer c, invoice i, transactions t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select t.QUANTITY from transactions t where t.QUANTITY <> '100' and i.CUSTID = d.CUSTID and t.ORDERID = d.ORDERID)